# Is it possible to obtain a type from decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

`decltype` returns a full type of an expression/entity. Is it possible to get only type?

For example, is it possible to make `p` to have type `T` in this case?

```
class T;
T t;
const T& tt = t;
decltype(tt) p; //decltype makes this const T& too as same as tt
```

Comment: `std::decay_t<decltype(tt)> p`

Comment: You cannot ever get the *name* of a type except through typeid(). `T` is a *type*. It may not even *have* a name.

Comment: @0x499602D2 thanks, it works. But it needs some changes: `std::decay<decltype(tt)>::type p`,

Comment: @Puppy well, sorry, I was talking about a type.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy std::decay_t<T> is an alias for std::decay<T>::type

Comment: @KABoissonneault I tried it but without success. As *cppreference* says, it is available only from `c++14`.

Comment: Even though it might be appropriate in this case, `std::decay` does more than just to remove cv-qualifiers and referenceness. For example, it converts function types to function pointers, and array types to pointers.

Comment: `remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<decltype(tt)>>`

Comment: @Victor Polevoy: What is the implied difference between "full type" and "only type"?

Comment: @AnT you are asking this question like you did not read the code snippet which clearly explains what I mean and/or answer which clearly explains how to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: You give one example, not a full specification. Do you need `const int` -> `int` as well ? You're using non-standard terms, it's up to you to define the terms. What about `int const* const`, how many `const` do you want removed?

Comment: @MSalters So why other people could understand me if it is not clear? :) I want to remove anything and remain only the type without any specifiers (const, volatile, pointer, reference, anything). Why do you think I accepted the answer then?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: The experts who understand why your question is ambiguous don't answer it; the people who answered it made an assumption based on **their** extrapolation of your example. I don't know why you accepted an answer that doesn't fulfill your criteria. For instance, it won't remove `const` from `int (*)(int const*)` so it fails your "remove any specifier".

Comment: @MSalters Okay. But about the answer - currently I don't need to work with the example you provided so the answer covers all of my use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on entirely on what you want to do in the cases of `cv T*` and `cv T[N]`. If in all of those cases you just want `T`, then you'll need to write a type trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct just_t
: std::conditional_t<std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<T>,T>::value,
                     tag<T>,
                     just_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>>
{ };                   

template <typename T>
struct just_t<T*> : just_t<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct just_t<T&> : just_t<T> { };

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct just_t<T[N]> : just_t<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct just_t<T[]> : just_t<T> { };
```

If you're okay with pointers staying as they are and arrays decaying into pointers, then simply:

```
template <typename T>
using just_t = std::decay_t<T>;
```

Comment: You can also have a template alias for just_t::type